# PHP array not displaying all values through loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I am writing a php function which appends content to a $results variable and will return all the results appended to it.

I have a variable $myArray which holds many separate arrays and looks like the below

```
Array(
[0] => ABC
[1] => DEF
[2] => GHI
[3] => JKL
 )
Array(
[0] => MNO
[1] => 123A
[2] => 123B
[3] => 123C
 )
Array(
[0] => orange
[1] => yellow
[2] => green
[3] => blue
 )
```

In my code i loop though content to generate buttons and data tot he screen. i would ideally like if the first button is pressed the contents of the first array (ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL), the second button (MNO, 123A,123B,123C) etc etc.

Here is my loop to generate content

```
for($index=0; $index < count($exampleArray); index++){
  $myArray = array_values(array_filter($exampleArray[$index]["Column2"]));
  $returnVariable .= '<td>
    <button type="button" class="open-my-modal btn btn-primary" 
        data-numbers="'.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($myArray), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" </td>';
```

The above code generates different buttons depending on the data that is being passed through, and to be sent to a modal. The part of the modal code where  i create an id is below

```
$returnVariable .= '<tr>
                        <td><span id ="value1"></span></td>
                        <td><span id ="value2"></span></td>
                        <td><span id ="value3"></span></td>
                        <td><span id ="value4"></span></td>
                    </tr>
```

Then i have a script where when the modal is opened i link the data, to the html id.

```
$returnVariable .= '<script>

$(document).ready(function () {             
$(".open-my-modal").click(function(){
  $("#value1").html($(this).data("numbers")[0]);
```

The problem is no matter what button the same information is being displayed. And the only data that is being passed though on any button is ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL.

I i call

```
$("#value1").html($(this).data("numbers")[0]); Only ABC will show.
```

if i call

```
$("#value1").html($(this).data("numbers")); It shows ABC up to JKL
```

The data is supposed to change dynamically depending on which button is clicked. 
MNO etc, or orange, yellow never shows up. it only is taking the first array, for every button.

The content will be looped though dynamically for example

```
<td><span id ="value1"></span></td> = ABC
                    <td><span id ="value2"></span></td>= DEF
                    <td><span id ="value3"></span></td>= GHI
                    <td><span id ="value4"></span></td>= HIJ
```

Next Button clicked values should =

```
<td><span id ="value1"></span></td> = MNO
                    <td><span id ="value2"></span></td>= 123A
                    <td><span id ="value3"></span></td>= 123B
                    <td><span id ="value4"></span></td>= 123C
```

etc, etc

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the *generated* HTML (not the PHP, the actual HTML and `<script>` that are seen in the browser)?

Comment: The script and html code for the modal is displayed above. What other code do you need to see?

Comment: Again, the *actual HTML* for the buttons, `data-...` attributes and all. Not the PHP. View Source in the browser, copy those parts, add to the question.

Comment: The first part of your code, `$myArray` should be a multi-dimensional array where the key could correspond to the button. For example, how does it know to display `MNO, 123A`... on pressing the second button? It needs something (a key) in `$myArray` to identify that...

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because `$myArray` is being overwritten. You posted:

```
Array(
[0] => ABC
[1] => DEF
[2] => GHI
[3] => JKL
 )
Array(
[0] => MNO
[1] => 123A
[2] => 123B
[3] => 123C
 )
Array(
[0] => orange
[1] => yellow
[2] => green
[3] => blue
 )
```

Well, the array keys `[0],[1],[2],[3]` are the same in each instance and there is nothing to "contain" each array.

You really need a multidimensional array, more like this:

```
[0] => [
    [0] => ABC
    [1] => DEF
    [2] => GHI
    [3] => JKL
],
[1] => [
    [0] => MNO
    [1] => 123A
    [2] => 123B
    [3] => 123C
],
// ...
```

If you use `var_dump($myArray[0]);` you will get the "first" set (arrays are 0-indexed):

```
[0] => ABC
[1] => DEF
[2] => GHI
[3] => JKL
```

And `var_dump($myArray[1]);` gives you the second set:

```
[0] => MNO
[1] => 123A
[2] => 123B
[3] => 123C
```

etc...

The key in the multi dimensional array can correspond to the button pressed, e.g.

- Button 1: `$myArray[0]`
- Button 2: `$myArray[1]`
- Button 3: `$myArray[2]`
- Button 4: `$myArray[3]`